# Активность кнопки по времени rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, button, haml

Проблема заключается в том, что понятия не имею как записать логику. Имеется страничка тех. поддержки, пользователь оставляет заявку, в личном кабинете у него доступна табличка с его обращением, где есть кнопки "просмотреть", "редактировать" и "удалить". Но нужно сделать так, чтобы кнопка "удалить" была доступна только 30 минут от времени создания заявки. Мне бы понять, где это прописать, и как. Мысль есть прописать в контролере, но логику пока до конца не могу разобрать.

```
if (request.created_at <= DateTime.now+1.minute &&  DateTime.now+1.minute > DateTime.now)
            = button_to 'Удалить', request_path(request),method: :delete, title: 'Удаление', class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Вы уверены, что хотите удалить?' } do
              %i.fa.fa-trash-o
            -#= link_to request_path(request), method: :delete, title: 'Удаление', class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Вы уверены, что хотите удалить?' } do
          - else
            = button_to 'Удалить', request_path(request),method: :delete, title: 'Удаление', class: 'btn btn-danger', disable: true, data: { confirm: 'Вы уверены, что хотите удалить?' } do
              %i.fa.fa-trash-o
```

На данный момент дошел лишь до этого, но что-то запутался, и, возможно, допущены ошибки и неправильная логика. Желательно простенький пример для рассмотрения и понимания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько шагов:

### 1. Назовем модель иначе, чем Request

На всякий случай. Потому что `request` и `response` в рельсах - зарезервированные имена для обращения к запросу и ответу от сервера. Если использовать `Request` для модели - явных ошибок от рельс вы не увидите, но потом можете внезапно столкнуться с проблемами.

Я называю такие модели `SiteRequest`, и использую `site_request` для хранения отдельной записи модели.

### 2. Проверять время нам нужно в двух местах

Во-первых, во вьюхе при выводе кнопки. Показывать кнопку, если с момента создания заявки прошло менее 30 минут. Но есть еще одно место:

> **Кейс:** 28 минут с момента создания заявки. Страница загрузилась, кнопка на ней видна. Пользователь кликнул по ней спустя 3 минуты. Заявку удаляем или нет? Ведь в момент клика по кнопке - прошла уже 31 минута с момента создания.

Если учесть этот кейс - нужно добавить условие на 30 минут и в экшн удаления заявки `site_requests#destroy`. Одно и то же условие в двух разных местах на сайте.

### 3. Сохраним условие в одном общем месте

Чтобы не писать и там, и там "Если прошло меньше 30 минут с момента создания задания" - запишем это условие, например, в методе модели:

```
class SiteRequest < ApplicationRecord
  # Ваш существующий код модели

  def allow_to_destroy?
    created_at + 30.minutes <= DateTime.now
  end
end
```

### 4. Используем метод модели для проверки

Во-первых - во вьюхе (написано на [slim](http://slim-lang.com/)):

```
- if site_request.allow_to_destroy?
  = link_to 'Удалить', site_request, method: :delete,
            title: 'Удаление',
            class: 'btn btn-danger',
            data: { confirm: 'Вы уверены, что хотите удалить?' } do
    i.fa.fa-trash-o
```

Во-вторых - в экшне `destroy`:

```
class SiteRequestsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    site_request = SiteRequest.find(params[:id])
    if site_request.allow_to_destroy?
      if site_request.destroy
        flash[:success] = 'Заявка успешно удалена'
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Заявку не удалось удалить'
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = 'С момента создания заявки прошло 30 минут, вы не можете ее удалить'
    end
    redirect_to :site_requests
  end
end
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но ошибка остается одна, что метод не может быть определен

Comment: В каком месте у вас ошибка? И как она звучит в оригинале? Undefined method?

Comment: Прошу меня простить. Ошибку нашел сам. не верно прописал во вьюхе метод. Но проблема в то, что даже после нажатия кнопки даже спустя 30 минут контролер удаляет запись

Comment: У вас там код `if site_request.allow_to_destroy?` такой? И если такой - что хранится в `site_request`? Должна одиночная запись модели `SiteRequest`. Но у вас, судя по ошибке, там лежит что-то другое.

Comment: Уже поправил говорю же. И вроде как кнопка стала пропадать. Сижу тестирую, благодарю за помощь. Использовал целую запись строки, и внимания не обратил, что не так

Comment: В чем проблема, то ли с проблемой timezone то с какими то непонятными магнитными бурями, но в условиях необходимо поставить unless вместо if и тогда программа становится адекватно реагировать на временные рамки

Answer (score -2):

Если заявка сохраняется в БД:
- То необходимо создать условие появление кнопки удалить и редактировать. Для этого советую  почитать документацию к библиотеке [Time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) . А дальше, простые математические и логические операции с колонкой "created_at" относящейся к конкретной заявке.
- Логику лучше всего писать в [Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) , что бы не засорять вьюхи.

Код не стал специально писать, так как информация в вопросе не способствует погружению в бизнес логику.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/155024)

Comment: @DenisBubnov содержится. То, что описано плохо, не значит, что его нет совсем.

Comment: @D-side, содержится, но такой ответ приведет к дополнительным уточнениям. Можно же расписать немного подробнее и конкретнее.

Comment: @DenisBubnov и тем не менее, ваш комментарий слабо стыкуется с содержанием этого сообщения. Оно не является дополнением к вопросу или комментарием, оно действительно пытается ответить на вопрос, даже если делает это плохо. Это плохой ответ, но ответ. Он заслуживает минусов, но не удаления. Готов снять минус, если его автор развернёт мысль.